# How to use IF Statement when there is #N/A Error

Tags: excel, if-statement, error-handling, excel-formula

I have a formula follow as below mentioned:

```
=IF(RC[1]=0,"matched",IF(RC[1]>0,"Short booked",IF(RC[1]<>0.01,"Excess booked",IF(RC[1]=#N/A,"GIT",0))))'
```

I am unable to get **GIT** as a text instead of **#N/A** error in a cell, what is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with an IFERROR wrapper.

```
=iferror(IF(RC[1]=0, "matched", IF(RC[1]>0, "Short booked", IF(RC[1]<>0.01, "Excess booked", 0))), "GIT")
```

However, I still see a logic hole problem as I'm pretty sure `IF(RC[1]<>0.01,...` will not be reached. Logical progression would suggest that should be `..., IF(RC[1]<0, "Excess booked", ...`.